# Optimizing a conditional join in MySQL that depends on the character length of the source table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, query-optimization

I'm using MySQL 5.7 and I'm trying to do a join with one of my source tables to a reference table in order to get the appropriate corresponding values. However, I'd like the join to be conditional so it can match according to the length of the value found in the source column.

Source Table

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|     Company_Name    |     NAICS_Code   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       Chem Inc      |        325       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     Joe's Farming   |       1112       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Reference Table

```
|---------------------|------------------|--------------------|------------------|
| NAICS_Code_3_Digit  |     NAICS_Code_  | NAICS_Code_4_Digit |    NAICS_Cod_    | 
|                     |   3D_Description |                    |  4D_Description  |   
|---------------------|------------------|--------------------|------------------|
|        325          |   Chemicals      |       3252         |  Resin and Rubber|
|---------------------|------------------|--------------------|------------------|
|        111          | Crop Production  |       1112         | Fruit and Nuts   |
|---------------------|------------------|----------------------------------------
```

Final Table

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|--------------------|
|     Company_Name    |     NAICS_Code   | NAICS_Code_3D_   |  NAICS_Code_4D     |     
|                     |                  |    Description   |   Description      |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------------------------|
|       Chem Inc      |        325       |     Chemicals    |        NULL        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|--------------------|
|     Joe's Farming   |       1112       |  Crop Production |    Fruit and Nuts  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|--------------------|
```

While I'm able to write a query that works, it takes an extremely long time and I' curious as to if there is a better way. Here's what I got so far:

```
SELECT src.Company_Name,
       src.NAICS_Code,
       CASE
           WHEN LENGTH(src.NAICS_Code < 3 THEN NULL
           ELSE ref.NAICS_Code_3D_Description
       END AS NAICS_Code_3D_Description,
       CASE
           WHEN LENGTH(src.NAICS_Code < 4 THEN NULL
           ELSE ref.NAICS_Code_4D Description
       END AS NAICS_Code_4D_Description
FROM source_table AS src
LEFT JOIN reference_table AS ref ON CASE
                                        WHEN LENGTH(src.NAICS_Code) = 4
                                             AND src.NAICS_Code = ref.NAICS_Code_4_Digit THEN 1
                                        WHEN LENGTH(src.NAICS_Code) = 3
                                             AND src.NAICS_Code = ref.NAICS_Code_3_Digit THEN 1
                                        ELSE 0
                                    END = 1;
```

Comment: Why are you storing in 2 fields the same data ? `NAICS_Code_3_Digit` can be retrieved in `FLOOR(NAICS_Code_4_Digit / 10)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be more efficient to `left join` twice:

- this avoids the need for the complicated logic in the `on` clause of the `join`
- conditions are exclusive so it will not generate duplicates in the resultset
- then you can use `coalesce()` in the `select` clause

So:

```
select
    s.compay_name,
    s.naics_code,
    coalesce(r1.naics_code_3d_description, r2.naics_code_3d_description) naics_code_3d_description,
    r2.naics_code_4d_description
from source_table s
left join reference_table r1 on r1.naics_code_3_digit = s.naics_code
left join reference_table r2 on r2.naics_code_4_digit = s.naics_code
```

If you want to evict source rows that did not match in the reference table, you can add a `where` clause, like:

```
where r1.naics_code_3_digit is not null or r2.naics_code_3d_description is not null
```